# Disable internet access from school tablets including custom hotspots

Tags: windows

I am a teacher at a high school, where every student has a (windows) tablet (administered by school staff). One problem currently is for example that students use the tablets to browse the web in class.

Now I suggested to implement that internet access is disabled by default (except for example the moodle page of the school) but the teacher can enable it by one click if needed.

An objection from colleagues was that this wouldn't help much, since for example a student could create a hotspot using his smartphone (via bluetooth or usb) or something like this.

So, is there any good solution which covers also those and other possible ways to circumvent the access control?

Comment: Something in here might give the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-restrictions-windows-10#cellular-and-connectivity

Comment: Being able to bypass it with a hotspot isn't even the point; the whole thing in general seems like it should be a _last resort_ "solution", rather than being the first thing to suggest. It's a school, not a prison.

Comment: IF you find a solution which is easy enough for all of your colleagues to understand, you can be sure that within days some of your students have learned to circumvent this. Rather, focus on creating tasks interesting enough for the students, where they may or may not use internet. Teach them the value or non-value of internet. You got them a tablet: they should be able to use ALL of its functions. When students are bored, they'll do what is more interesting to them than the lesson. 30 years ago, we played games or passed written messages in class. It's not so much different from that.

Comment: @1NN: No its much different from that. 1. Platforms like tiktok are designed to draw the attention of users, that they spend much time as possible on the platform. 2. It is much easier to hide what you are doing. 3. Even if the lesson is very interesting and engaging, you now compete against all the "interesting" things all over the internet (and not against writing messages on paper).

Comment: Do you have an IT Manager in your school, or does this have to be a do-it-yourself solution? Is there someone who could set up a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) on your school's internet access?

Comment: In Germany there are services which can greatly reduce this task for you. See for example the [Jugendschutzprogramm für Schulen](https://www.jusprogdns.com/schulen/) or https://flashstart.com/de/webfilterung-fuer-schulen/

Answer (score 1):

You could program the Windows Firewall to block all outgoing
connections, allowing only the ones that Windows needs.

This is a change that no teacher can disable with one click,
and that adding a mobile hotspot won't change anything.
To undo it would require knowing the Administrator's password,
which you could keep secret.

The Windows Firewall is mostly already prepared for a total block of
all outgoing connections. You will find that the firewall already
contains many outgoing Allow rules which under the default situation
have no function, since all outgoing connections are allowed by default.
But since "Allow" rules have a greater priority than "Block",
these rules will have meaning after you introduce a blanket
Block rule.

You will need to test well that the tablets still function correctly
afterward. This small change can have a large impact.

Comment: Any idea of how to allow the teachers to enable/disable networking by one click? Are there software solutions for this already?

Comment: What part of networking? Local or internet or selective?